# cakephp foreach loop only display the first letter from title

Tags: php, cakephp, module, model, controller

i want to display `data` from database and also i have created function in `model file` which is showing data from database but all values are shown in the `array format`.

problem is that when i print `echo $values['title'];` in foreach loop it is showing only first letter from `title` array??

**model code**

```
 function reviewcitypage()  
 {

 $cacheKey = 'city_page';
 GigaCache::set(array('duration'=>"+1 minutes",'path'=>CACHE));
 $cachedCategoryData = GigaCache::read($cacheKey);

    if($cachedCategoryData && !cr('DynamicPage.field'))
    {   
        $recentactivity = $cachedCategoryData;
    }else
    {
        $recentactivity= $this->find("list",array("conditions"=>array("status"=>1),'fields'=>array('title','body','rating'),'recursive'=>-1,'limit'=>10));  
        //dont't set cache if dynamic field
        if(!cr('DynamicPage.field'))
        {
          GigaCache::set(array('duration'=>"+1 minutes",'path'=>CACHE));
          GigaCache::write($cacheKey,$recentactivity);
        }
    }


    return $recentactivity;
```

}

**view file**

```
$ReviewObj = cri('Review');
      $recentactivity = $ReviewObj->reviewcitypage();

      foreach ($recentactivity as $name => $value){ 

          foreach($value as $values)
            {             
                echo $values['title'];
            }
      }
```

**problem is solved now thanks for support **

```
i have changed the code in model file and it is woking now

$recentactivity= $this-
>find("all",array("conditions"=>array("status"=>1),'recursive'=>-1,
'limit'=>10));
```

Comment: what is the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($recentactivity);`. Show us

Comment: @Anant i want to display `data` into different div in view file

Answer (score 3):

Your find() query is preparing the data as a `'list'`. in cake lists are always key => value pair arrays. so in your view when you use the second foreach loop you are saying foreach character in a string...do.....

in your example `$value` can only be a string. foreaching it can only make $values a single char.

Let me know if you still unsure what i mean. not the best at explaining what i mean

> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list

Because you are after 3 fields I suggest using either `first` or `all` in place of `list` as the first argument in the find() method.

Comment: jason you have any example how can i show data in view file from model file ??

Comment: well because you are after 3 fields I suggest using either `'first'` or `all` in place of `list` as the first argument in the find() method. What is your rationale around choosing `list` as your return type?

Comment: well im facing problem is that i want to display data in view file ?? do you have skype?

Comment: Please tell us the resolution to your problem

Comment: i have changed the code in model file and it is working now
`list to all `

Comment: Because I was technically right about `list` being incorrect can you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109795/discussion-between-farhan-dharsi-and-jason-joslin).